# Fix piTest causing NullReturnValsMutator gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, junit, pitest

i have a method which is returning an Response(entity class), Both Response and Request are entities defined using lombak.

```
public Response get(String id) {
    Request request = Request.builder()
            .id(id)
            .build();
    try {
      return service.post(request, Response.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      var msg = "Failed calling the service";
      log.error(msg, e);
      throw new IllegalStateException(msg, e);
    }
  }
```

Test methods:

```
public void testGet() {

    Request request = Request.builder()
            .id(“123”)
            .build();
    Response response = Response.builder().id("123").build();

    when(service.post(eq(request), eq(Response.class))).thenReturn(response);

    assertEquals(response, controller.get(“123”);
  }



@Test
  public void testException() {
  Request request = Request.builder()
            .id(“123”)
            .build();

    when(service.post(eq(request), eq(Response.class))).thenReturn(response);

   Exception exception = assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class, () -> {
     controller.get(”123”);
   });
   String expectedMessage = "Failed calling the service";
   String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();

   assertTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));

  }
```

When i run ./gradlew pitest, it errors out saying "replaced return value with null for Response::get" with this message below:

```
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.returns.NullReturnValsMutator
>> Generated 1 Killed 1 (100%)
> KILLED 1 SURVIVED 0 TIMED_OUT 0 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0
```

Could anyone please help with how to resolve the NullReturnValsMutator error here.

Comment: What do the tests for this code look like?

Comment: @henry i have updated the above with test methods i wrote for them.

Comment: The code you posted accepts a String id, the first test you posted passes a Request object, so is hitting a different method. Please post enough code to see how the two methods are related.

Comment: @henry thanks for correcting it . Yes it has to be string ! Got the wrong methods pasted here . Corrected it .

Comment: If you manually change the method to return null and run the tests, what happens?

Comment: i tried that, it just says  WARNING : No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters . I actually want to return the Object Response instead as this method will be used by other classes too.

Comment: I mean, make change the method to return null. Then run the normal tests (not pitest).

Comment: @henry yeah junit tests works when we modify the tests also to assert null.

Comment: If you can create a minimal executable project (i.e a fully working project with a buildscript) that reproduces the issue I can take a look.